# Error while Image loading from database

Tags: asp.net

I am using a generic handler for loading Image from data bases. Its work fine when when I hardcode the `ImageID` in the query string when call handler. But it's giving error of different type when I dynamically pass value from query string (from datatable):

> ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open.

OR

> Invalid operation. The connection is closed.

Here is the code of handler

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    Int64 id = Convert.ToInt64(context.Request.QueryString["adid"]);
    dt = GetRecpDetailsByID(id);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        //context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dt.Rows[0][2]);
    }
}

public DataTable GetRecpDetailsByID(Int64 reid)
{
    try
    {
        obj_DB.Open();
        obj_sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("GetRecpDetailsByID", obj_DB.GetDBConnection());
        obj_sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        obj_sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@rid", reid));
        obj_sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter();

        obj_dt = new DataTable();
        obj_sqlda.SelectCommand = obj_sqlcmd;
        obj_sqlda.Fill(obj_dt);

        return obj_dt;
    }
    finally
    {
        obj_DB.Close();
    }
}
```

And here is the HTML and server-side code on ASPX page of call handler

```
  <img id="img2" alt="Image" runat="server" src='<%#"ImageReqHAndler.ashx?adid="+Eval("Reid")%>' width="179" height="148" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is shown when a connection object's open method is not called
u need something like:

```
SqlConnection conn = (SqlConnection)obj_DB.GetDBConnection();
conn.Open();
```